# RabbitMQ conf file location

Tags: rabbitmq

Where do I put my `rabbitmq.conf` file and how do I make it known to the `rabbitmq-server`?

All documentation and what I can find only clarifies that this file is not there initially, and the example config file is referenced. Official doc says that I can override the `RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE` env variable. It is unset on my system, but how would I set it so that it is known to `rabbitmq-server`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Taschi mentioned, the default location of the `rabbitmq.conf` file is `/etc/rabbitmq` folder.

Also, you can place it in a custom location and let the `rabbitmq-server` know the location by setting in in the `rabbitmq-env.conf` file.

Contents of `rabbitmq-env.conf` file

```
CONFIG_FILE=/path/to/rabbitmq.conf
```

Reference: https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#config-location

Answer (score 1):

By default, the location is at /etc/rabbitmq, according to https://medium.com/@lukaszlenart/how-to-configure-rabbitmq-properly-fa39b2d4cda2.

How to properly set the env variable depends on your operating system, but you could just do it in a startup shell script.

Answer (score 0):

**ON MAC**

If installed via Homebrew you possible find the `rabbitmq-env.conf` file at

`/opt/homebrew/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf`

One way to find out as well is to read the `plist` file to see the config location

- Once you start rabbitmq via `brew services start rabbitmq`
- It displays "rabbitmq started {user} ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.rabbitmq.plist"
- RUN: `vim ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.rabbitmq.plist`

This should display certain file location such as config that you need.